# selecting database name, table name and column name.

Tags: mysql, sql, identifier

The MySql manual [states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifier-qualifiers.html):

***Similarly, to retrieve from a table 't' in database 'db1' and from a table 't' in database 'db2' in the same statement, you must refer to columns in those tables as 'db1.t.col_name' and 'db2.t.col_name'.***

How would one go about creating such a select statement?

Comment: Bear in mind that the current mysql user must have access to both databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different alias names for the tables that have the same name but are in different DBs

```
select d1.col1, d2.col1
from db1.table1 d1
inner join db2.table1 d2 on d1.id = d2.id
```